# UITableView push to My webView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiwebview, push

I'd like to start by apologising as I'm sure this question has been answered, in various forms on this site and others, but I just can't seem to implement any similar threads

It's just I have been trying to push a array of search engines into my webView, 
I have populated the table with a .plist or NSMutableArray and I have an array of both kinds with Url's in I have manages to load a subview but I an really struggling to get my web view loading.
I think I'm ok until didSelectRowAtIndexPath and the webView load request. Ok thinking about it I have only populated the table and put  IBOUTLET (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView and synthesised it in my WebViewController.
And as Background my TableViewController is embedded in a NavigationController and a WebView in a UIViewController
If anyone is willing to help me out I'm more than willing to donate as this has caused way too many sleepless nights.

Here is a link to my project if it would help anyone http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28335617/TableViewArrays.zip

Thank you very much for any help offered

Here is my TableViewController.h

```
@class WebViewController;
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource,   UITableViewDelegate> {
       WebViewController *viewController;
    IBOutlet UITableView *mytableView;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *mytableView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) WebViewController *viewController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *searchData, *tableData, *tableUrl;
@end
```

Here is my TableViewController.m

```
    #import "TableViewController.h"
    #import "TableAppDelegate.h"
    #import "WebViewController.h"
    @interface TableViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation TableViewController
    @synthesize mytableView;
    @synthesize viewController;
    @synthesize searchData, tableData, tableUrl;
     NSMutableArray *searchData, *tableData, *tableUrl;



    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];



     tableUrl = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [tableUrl addObject: @"http://www.google.com"];
    [tableUrl addObject: @"http://www.bing.com"];
[tableUrl addObject: @"http://www.dogpile.com"];
[tableUrl addObject: @"http://www.wikipedia.com"];
[tableUrl addObject: @"http://www.ask.com"];
[tableUrl addObject: @"http://www.yahoo.com"];
    [tableUrl addObject: @"http://www.aol.com"];
[tableUrl addObject: @"http://www.altavista.com"];
[tableUrl addObject: @"http://www.gigablast.com"];
[tableUrl addObject: @"http://www.msn.com"];
[tableUrl addObject: @"http://www.mamma.com"];
    self.title = @"Search Engines";


            //ARRAY FOR PLIST
       // Find out the path of recipes.plist
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"searchData"      ofType:@"plist"];
                       searchData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

        // Load the file content and read the data into arrays 
       NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        tableData = [dict objectForKey:@"SearchEngines"];
       // tableUrl = [dict objectForKey:@"SearchAddress"];

   // NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sEArray" ofType:@"plist"];
                     // sEArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

      // NSString *urlArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"urlsArray" ofType:@"plist"];
                      //urlsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:urlArray];

    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {

        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }

     - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section
    {

        // Return the number of rows in the section.
       return [self.tableData count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell == nil) {


        }

        // Configure the cell...
         NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        return cell;
     }








    #pragma mark - Table view delegate
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    }
     @end
```

And here is my WebViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface WebViewController : UIViewController {


    NSMutableArray *tableURL;
     }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tableUrl;
    @end
```

And WebViewController.m

```
    #import "TableAppDelegate.h"
    #import "TableViewController.h"
    #import "WebViewController.h"

   @interface WebViewController ()

   @end

   @implementation WebViewController 

   @synthesize tableUrl;
   @synthesize webView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested. Add SequgeIdentifier "WebView" in IB

in tableviewcontroller add:

```
        - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
    ...
        tableUrl = [dict objectForKey:@"SearchAddress"];
        }

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"WebView" sender:self];
    }


    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"WebView"])
        {
            WebViewController *webViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

            NSIndexPath *selectedPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            webViewController.tableUrl = [tableUrl objectAtIndex:[selectedPath row]];
            [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedPath animated:YES];
        }

    }
```

in webviewcontroller

```
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController {
        NSString *tableURL;
    }
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *tableUrl;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:tableUrl];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your reply, I can't tell you how relieved, I am. It finally works, I don't want to push my luck but could I ask a quickie... Is it OK in Interface builder to create the segue from TableViewController to the webView as when I hooked it up from the prototype cell it pushed a nested view, it was fully loaded but had to hit the back button twice , But hooked up from the TableViewController it works great.
Again Thank You for taking a look

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is not working?

Looking at your code, I immediately see that you cell initiation code is empty

if (cell == nil) {

}

I think you should initiate your cell with something like this:

cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

Comment: Thanks for taking a look I have applied the Cell Initiation